# It's possible to know owner of a analytics script having id UA-XXXX?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site developed by a third party, that might have a mistake and wrote another analytics script that is not mine in my site. Since I have the script I have the ID UA-XXXX, is there a way to know who owns this analytics account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no active service that can help you as you can't get the information from Google. They state their policy about identifying the owner of a Google Analytics id here:-

AnalyticsPro.Aruna said:

> Unfortunately, due to account security issues, we're unable to
>   disclose or add logins to Google Analytics accounts.

**Third-Party Alternatives**

1. [ReverseInternet.com](http://%20ReverseInternet.com%20and%20eWhois)
2. [eWhois](https://ewhois.com/)
3. [Spyontheweb](http://www.spyonweb.com/)